# Operar con potencias de decimales en shell

Tags: bash, shell, script

Estoy intentando hacer un script en shell que coja datos numéricos que suelen ser decimales del tipo 0,00004 y tengo que elevarlos al cuadrado. Usando "bc" el resultado me sale 0.

Ejemplo:

```
echo "(0.0000003+0.0000005)^2"|bc
0
```

Mirando la ayuda de bc, dice que puedo elevar números a potencias siempre y cuando sean numeros enteros

¿En que fallo? Si sabéis otro método sin usar bc me da lo mismo... ¿Alguien conoce alguna otra manera de hacer operaciones dentro de un script que sea algo más flexible en cuanto hay que hacer una cuenta un poco más compleja?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Podrías utilizar ksh, que tiene mejor manejo de operaciones matemáticas. Sin embargo, probablemente sea más comprensible hacerlo con Awk. Danos un ejemplo de cómo es tu archivo y qué quieres conseguir para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio bc no soporta tipo `float` pero si decimales fijos, pasale el numero de posiciones decimales que queres usar para las operaciones con `scale` si es omitido (by default) este valor es 0, asi que redondea a enteros

```
$ echo "scale=20; (0.0000003+0.0000005)^2"|bc
.00000000000064
```